# Update input value on change using a parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to replace any spaces in my input on change. I am using `ng-change` directive to accomplish that. I would normally write my code like this because I want the `removeInvalidCharacters` function to be reusable hence the model being passed as parameter.

```
<input model="vm.model.code" ng-change="vm.removeInvalidCharacters(vm.model.code)" />
```

and JS

```
vm.removeInvalidCharacters = function(text) {
  text = text.replace(/ /g, '');
};
```

I have read on the airbnb javascript style guide that this is a bad practice and we should return the value. To be exact we shouldn't "mutate a parameter" ([Never reassign parameters](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#functions--mutate-params)). What is the right way to do it and still keep the reusable function?

Comment: Not entirely clear on what exactly is being asked. You shouldn't come in behind a user during input and change their value "out from under their feet". If you need to clean up input, do it on form submission or the-like. If you need to validate, use regex to just catch patterns your cleanup method can't handle.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-change` is a directive that gets triggered every time there is a change in the model through the template.

In your code you are declaring a variable 'text' as a parameter with the value of 'vm.model.code'. But your changes are being made to the local variable 'text' and not in the variable used in the template

Use this instead:

```
vm.removeInvalidCharacters = function(text) {
  vm.model.code = text.replace(/ /g, '');
};
```

Edit:

If what you are looking for is passing the variable as reference instead of parameter check this answer:
[Pass $scope variable to function by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28235514/pass-scope-variable-to-function-by-reference)

Comment: That's what I wanted to do in the first place but what if I wanted to make `vm.removeInvalidCharacters` generic? e.g. change any of the model's properties vm.model.email etc. What I have been suggesting by the use of local 'text' is the way of mutating the parameter but what if I wanted to apply some common practices to this scenario?

Comment: What you are looking for is to pass a parameter as a reference instead of parameter which is not possible in Javascript without a workaround, also, Angular.js needs to be aware of the changes so it can do a digest cycle and apply the changes so I would recommend using the model instead because of that. If that doesn't stop you I updated my answer with an existing answer with a working workaround @LazioTibijczyk